# Firefox Triggers 'dragenter' twice

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a FireFox bug?

I have the latest version of FireFox (well, as of now, v55.0.3).

I made this test awhile back to get a hang of HTML drag-and-drop. The 6 boxes at the top can be dragged onto each other, and each distinct event type logs in its own box below, plus all events log in the first box (to show the firing order).

In Chrome, the 'dragenter' appears once in its box when I start to drag an element, but in FireFox, it appears twice in its box.

What's going on??

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codesmith32/q3n3vwqq/), and below is the full source:

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
    .drag {width:200px; height:200px; margin:10px; float:left; overflow:hidden; font:bold 20pt arial; text-align:center}
    .drag:nth-child(2n) {background-color:#20E020}
    .drag:nth-child(2n+1) {background-color:#2020E0}
    #logs {position:absolute; bottom:0}
    .log {float:left; width:100px; height:80px; border:1px solid #a0a0a0; padding:10px; overflow:auto; color:#a0a0a0; font:normal 10pt arial}
    .log::first-line {color:black}
    #ALL {background-color:#e0e0e0}
</style>
</head><body>
<div class="drag" draggable="true"><p>0</p></div>
<div class="drag" draggable="true"><p>1</p></div>
<div class="drag" draggable="true"><p>2</p></div>
<div class="drag" draggable="true"><p>3</p></div>
<div class="drag" draggable="true"><p>4</p></div>
<div class="drag" draggable="true"><p>5</p></div>
<div id="logs">
    <div class="log" id="ALL"></div>
    <div class="log" id="click"></div>
    <div class="log" id="drag"></div>
    <div class="log" id="dragstart"></div>
    <div class="log" id="dragend"></div>
    <div class="log" id="dragover"></div>
    <div class="log" id="dragenter"></div>
    <div class="log" id="dragleave"></div>
    <div class="log" id="drop"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
dvs=document.getElementsByClassName("drag");
var logs = {
    ALL: document.getElementById("ALL"),
    click: document.getElementById("click"),
    drag: document.getElementById("drag"),
    dragstart: document.getElementById("dragstart"),
    dragend: document.getElementById("dragend"),
    dragover: document.getElementById("dragover"),
    dragenter: document.getElementById("dragenter"),
    dragleave: document.getElementById("dragleave"),
    drop: document.getElementById("drop")
}
function log(lg,msg) {
    if(lg in logs) logs[lg].innerHTML = (msg + '<br>' + logs[lg].innerHTML).slice(0,1000);
    if(lg!="drag" && lg!="dragover") logs.ALL.innerHTML = (msg + '<br>' + logs.ALL.innerHTML).slice(0,1000);
}

for(var d,i=0;i<dvs.length;i++) (function(){var _i=i, d=dvs[i];
    d.onclick = function(ev) {log("click","click: "+_i)}
    d.ondrag = function(ev) {log("drag","drag: "+_i)}
    d.ondragstart = function(ev) {log("dragstart","dragstart: "+_i); ev.dataTransfer.setData('x-application/x-null','')}
    d.ondragend = function(ev) {log("dragend","dragend: "+_i)}
    d.ondragover = function(ev) {log("dragover","dragover: "+_i); ev.preventDefault()}
    d.ondragenter = function(ev) {log("dragenter","dragenter: "+_i)}
    d.ondragleave = function(ev) {log("dragleave","dragleave: "+_i)}
    d.ondrop = function(ev) {log("drop","drop: "+_i)}
})();
</script>
</body></html>
```